# Use `capture_tpu_profile` in AI Platform

Tags: google-cloud-platform, tpu, gcp-ai-platform-training

we are trying to capture TPU profiling data while running our training task on AI Platform. Following [this tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/tpu/docs/cloud-tpu-tools). All needed information like TPU name getting from our model output.

config.yaml:

```yaml
trainingInput:
  scaleTier: BASIC_TPU
  runtimeVersion: '1.15' # also tried '2.1'
```

task submitting command:

```sh
export DATE=$(date '+%Y%m%d_%H%M%S') && \
gcloud ai-platform jobs submit training "imaterialist_image_classification_model_${DATE}" \
--region=us-central1 \
--staging-bucket='gs://${BUCKET}' \
--module-name='efficientnet.main' \
--config=config.yaml \
--package-path="${PWD}/efficientnet" \
-- \
--data_dir='gs://${BUCKET}/tfrecords/' \
--train_batch_size=8 \
--train_steps=5 \
--model_dir="gs://${BUCKET}/algorithms_training/imaterialist_image_classification_model/${DATE}" \
--model_name='efficientnet-b4' \
--skip_host_call=true \
--gcp_project=${GCP_PROJECT_ID} \
--mode=train
```

When we tried to run `capture_tpu_profile` with name that our model got from master:

```
capture_tpu_profile --gcp_project="${GCP_PROJECT_ID}" --logdir='gs://${BUCKET}/algorithms_training/imaterialist_image_classification_model/20200318_005446' --tpu_zone='us-central1-b' --tpu='<tpu_IP_address>'
```

we got this error:

```
  File "/home/kovtuh/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/distribute/cluster_resolver/tpu_cluster_resolver.py", line 480, in _fetch_cloud_tpu_metadata
    "constructor. Exception: %s" % (self._tpu, e))
ValueError: Could not lookup TPU metadata from name 'b'<tpu_IP_address>''. Please doublecheck the tpu argument in the TPUClusterResolver constructor. Exception: <HttpError 404 when requesting https://tpu.googleapis.com/v1/projects/<GCP_PROJECT_ID>/locations/us-central1-b/nodes/<tpu_IP_address>?alt=json returned "Resource 'projects/<GCP_PROJECT_ID>/locations/us-central1-b/nodes/<tpu_IP_address>' was not found". Details: "[{'@type': 'type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ResourceInfo', 'resourceName': 'projects/<GCP_PROJECT_ID>/locations/us-central1-b/nodes/<tpu_IP_address>'}]">
```

Seems like TPU device isn't connected to our project when provided in AI Platform, but what project is connected to and can we get an access to such TPUs to capture it's profile?

Comment: what output do you get when you run on the cloud shell "$ctpu ls"

Comment: It shows nothing.
I also found in logs some configuration like `--tpu_node={"project": "nxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx-ml", "zone": "us-central1-c", "tpu_node_name": "cmle-training-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx-tpu"}` and tried to give this information to `projects.locations.nodes.get` TPU API method, but GCP says that I don't have permissions to do that.